# How to sync users from SQL database to WSO2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to sync my user list from sql server database to WSO2 identity server.
How can i achieve this. Is there any api in WSO2 identity server to sync user list at once.
Or any bulk user upload file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. WSO2 IS supports bulk user uploading via CSV/ Excel file. You need
   to export data in SQL DB to a CSV file and import that file into
   WSO2 IS userstore.
   https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-users/#importing-users
2. Another option is using SCIM /Bulk endpoint (https://anuradha-15.medium.com/scim-2-0-bulk-operation-support-in-wso2-identity-server-5-10-0-8041577a4fe3), you have to write your own script to export data from SQL DB and form the data into the format that SCIM supports